# How can I exit this while loop and make it so when someone types "? quit" the program will terminate

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RectAngleObj {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sPeri = "perimeter";
    String sArea = "area";
    String sQues = "?";
    String sQuit = "quit";
    String f;
    String g;
    String h;
    String j;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        f = sc.next(); // assigns the first standard input to f (can either be ? or quit)
        g = sc.next(); // assigns the second word from standard input to g (can either be perimeter or area)
        if(f.equals(sQues)) { // if first word is equal to "?" then the if statements continue
            if (g.equals(sPeri)) { // if the second word is equal to "perimeter" print out result
                double a = sc.nextDouble(), // assigns next four doubles to a, b, c, d
                       b = sc.nextDouble(),
                       c = sc.nextDouble(),
                       d = sc.nextDouble();
                RectAngle3 r = new RectAngle3(a, b, c, d); // creates an object of RectAngle3 with dimensions of a, b, c, d
                System.out.println("Perimeter of (" + r.rectNums() + "): "  + r.rectPeri());
            } if (g.equals(sArea)) { // if the second word is equal to "area" print out result
                double a = sc.nextDouble(), // assigns next four doubles to a, b, c, d
                       b = sc.nextDouble(),
                       c = sc.nextDouble(),
                       d = sc.nextDouble();
                RectAngle3 r = new RectAngle3(a, b, c, d); // creates an object of RectAngle3 with dimensions of a, b, c, d
                System.out.println("Area of (" + r.rectNums() + "): " + r.rectArea());
            }
    }
    }
    }
}
```

I want the while loop to end naturally without using System.exit(0); or break;
please help!

Ideally if someone types "? quit" the program will end.

I don't receive any errors, the loop just continues forever... not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried using the key word "break"?...

Comment: @WyattLowery Yep, don't want to use that though.

Comment: FWIW, it would probably be best to read a line at a time and then split it into words. Otherwise one line - with too few or two many words - might accidentally affect the next. This will also prevent an exception when only one of the 'next' calls is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your loop so that it has a exit condition, instead of using `while (sc.hasNext()` and add a condition in your "question" block to check to see if the user entered `sQuit`, for example

```
boolean hasQuit = false;
do {
    f = sc.next(); // assigns the first standard input to f (can either be ? or quit)
    g = sc.next(); // assigns the second word from standard input to g (can either be perimeter or area)
    if (f.equals(sQues)) { // if first word is equal to "?" then the if statements continue
        if (g.equals(sQuit)) {
            hasQuit = true;
        } else if (g.equals(sPeri)) { // if the second word is equal to "perimeter" print out result
            //...
        } else if (g.equals(sArea)) { // if the second word is equal to "area" print out result
            //...
        }
    }
} while (!hasQuit);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad it could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Going off your comment that `f` should be either `?` or `quit`, and that you don't want to use `break` or `System.exit(0)`, you can do it like this:

```
if(f.equals(sQuit)) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `return`. if you return from main, your program will exit (unless there are threads running in the background)